# Power Query Group By not merging rows with same ID

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I have a table structure given below. I am using Group By in power query to merge the data based on the ID. Since the name is different it seems the power query is not merging the data in one row.

I want the data to be in one row for the same ID and the name I want is for whatever is the name in the last row for that ID.

I hope I could explain my issue well enough. Thanks for your help,

Input

| ID | Name | Q1 Sales | Q2 Sales | Q3 Sales | Q4 Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Demo | 100 | 200 | 300 |  |
| A1 | Demo1 |  |  |  | 400 |

Output

| ID | Name | Q1 Sales | Q2 Sales | Q3 Sales | Q4 Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Demo1 | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 |

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"ID"}, {{"All", each _, type table [ID=nullable text, Name=nullable text, Q1 Sales=nullable number, Q2 Sales=nullable number, Q3 Sales=nullable number, Q4 Sales=nullable number]}}),
#"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All", {"Name", "Q1 Sales", "Q2 Sales", "Q3 Sales", "Q4 Sales"}, {"Name", "Q1 Sales", "Q2 Sales", "Q3 Sales", "Q4 Sales"})
in
#"Expanded All"
```

Comment: In your sample data, you have Demo1 in your latest data and as a result if you apply Max(Name) will work. But what if you have Demo1 in row 1 and Demo in row 2? In this case you will still get Demo1 in the name column and if you need the value from latest row, it's wrong! Also you need a row_number or date type column in your table to identify your latest row between a group.

Comment: @mkRabbani You are right it will not work in the cases where the situation is reversed and will not give accurate results in all the cases. Can you suggest the approach to use?.  I understand adding a new row number column but how to do the comparison part.

Comment: You can add a column like row number or datetime. Then you have to first search max row_no/datetime per id first. Then join the result with your main table to find the latest name. And again a join with your group by output. this will give you your expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in the group dialogue:

[image]

[image]